# What computations would advance math knowledge a lot?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, computer-science, big-list

Suppose we where given a super computer that would be capable of computing anything, but only for one day. We could for instance compute many of the Ramsey numbers. What would be some computations that would expand our knowledge of mathematics, and would give us results that would be used by many other mathematicians?

---

Example of an answer:

The Ramsey number $R(n,m)$ is the smallest integer $j$ such that $K_j$ must always contain a monochromatic red $K_n$ or a monochromatic blue $K_m$ when its edges are colored red or blue. A lot of effort has been made to calculate the Ramsey numbers. But even "small" Ramsey numbers like $R(5,5)$ are not well known (although it is known to be between $43$ and $49$). However these bounds become a lot worse for even slightly smaller Ramsey numbers like $R(10,9)$ for which the bound is $581-12677$. The computer could then be used to calculate a few thousand Ramsey numbers.

Comment: I'd ask for the answer to life, the universe, and everything. But, the computer would just return "42".

Comment: Just to be clear the computer can only brute force stuff, it's not like it's a genius or something, it's just insanely powerful.

Comment: @DavidMitra What's that 42 joke about? I've seen the number referenced a few times recently, but didn't manage to get it. **Edit:** OK, [got it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29). Never imagined it would be something one would find on wikipedia.

Comment: It's from the hitchiker's guide to the galaxy.

Comment: Would an exact value for $R(5,5)$ advance mathematics significantly?  It's not clear how.  As far as I know the only application of $R(5,5)$ is repelling alien attacks.

Comment: @MJD good one, well I don't know if it would advance mathematics siginificantly buth the ramsey numbers are used for a lot of other constructions, and the result would probably be cited more than a couple of times.

Comment: The computer could also look for other structures like graphs or polytopes etc.

Comment: How does "just for one day" put any restriction on "capable of computing anything"?

Comment: It doesn't, you can compute anything you want with it. What I meant is that the computer wouldn't be available for ever, so the existence of the computer would not allow us to solve NP problems almost  immediately in the future.